# AngularJS UI-router stateprovider issue

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

Im currently using Ionic and was playing with a app with tabs. (I.e has a bottom bar with icons).

Right now I want to remove it but ended messing up the routing. The devtools does not show any errors. I cannot transit from login page to main "posts" page. On login, clicking the login button does do anything. I have edited the state.go('') in the controllers accordingly.

Ill show before and after the changes. 
Would it make sense to remove views :{} totally? I find it complicates things and I do not use nested views. Not sure if modal page requires views.
Appreciate some help/ advice on how to get around the error.

**Before**

```
    .state('tab', {
      url: '/tab',
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
    })
   // --------Authenticate states ----------------
   .state('auth', {
      url: '/auth',
      templateUrl: 'templates/auth.html',
      controller: 'StartCtrl'
    })
    .state('register', {
      url: '/register',
      templateUrl: 'templates/register.html',
      controller: 'AuthCtrl',
    })
    .state('login', {
      url: '/login',
      templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
      controller: 'AuthCtrl',
    })

    // ---------- Main states ---------------------

    .state('tab.posts', {
      url: '/posts',
      views: {
        'tab-posts': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-posts.html',
          controller: 'PostsCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tab.newpost', {
      url: '/newpost',
      views: {
        'tab-posts': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-newpost.html',
          controller: 'NavCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tab.posts.view', {
      url: '/posts/:postId',           
      views: {
        'tab-posts@tab': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-showpost.html',
          controller: 'PostViewCtrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tab.profile', {
      url: '/users/:userId',  
      views: {
        'tab-posts': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-profile.html',
          controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
        }
      }
    })
```

**After**

```
.state('/', {
  url: '/',
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'templates/tab-posts.html'
})
// --------Authenticate states ----------------
.state('auth', {
  url: '/auth',
  templateUrl: 'templates/auth.html',
  controller: 'StartCtrl'
})

.state('register', {
  url: '/register',
  templateUrl: 'templates/register.html',
  controller: 'AuthCtrl',
  resolve: {
    user: function(Auth){
      return Auth.resolveUser();
    }
  }
})
.state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
  controller: 'AuthCtrl',
  resolve: {
    user: function(Auth){
      return Auth.resolveUser();
    }
  }
})

//----------- Main states--------------------

.state('posts', {
  url: '/posts',
  views: {
    'posts': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-posts.html',
      controller: 'PostsCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('newpost', {
  url: '/newpost',
  views: {
    'posts': {  
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-newpost.html',
      controller: 'NavCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('posts.view', {
  url: '/posts/:postId',
  views: {
    'posts@': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-showpost.html',
      controller: 'PostViewCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('profile', {
  url: '/users/:userId',   
  views: {
    'posts': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/tab-profile.html',
      controller: 'ProfileCtrl',
    }
  }
});
```

**Updated for Levi**

```
    app.factory('Auth', function($firebase, $firebaseAuth, FIREBASE_URL, $rootScope) {

      var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);
      var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);            

      var Auth = {
        register: function (user) {
          return auth.$createUser(user.email, user.password);
        },
        login: function (user) {
          return auth.$authWithPassword(user);  
        },
        logout: function() {                     
          auth.$unauth();
        },
        resolveUser: function() {
          return auth.$waitForAuth();          
        },
        signedIn: function() {
          return !!Auth.user.provider;
        },
        createProfile: function (user) {
          var profile = {
            username: user.username,     
            md5_hash: user.md5_hash
          };
          var profileRef = $firebase(ref.child('profile'));
          return profileRef.$set(user.uid, profile);
        },
        user: {}
      };

  auth.$onAuth(function (user){
    if(user) {
      angular.copy(user, Auth.user);
      Auth.user.profile = $firebase(ref.child('profile').child(Auth.user.uid)).$asObject();
      console.log(Auth.user);
    } else {
      console.log('logged out');

      if (Auth.user && Auth.user.profile) {
        Auth.user.profile.$destroy();
      }
      angular.copy({}, Auth.user);
    }
  });

  return Auth;
});
```

**Image for error trace**
[image: Image for error when resolveUser is deleted from Login in app.js]

Comment: why do u resolve user before go to login state ?

Comment: I mean, if someone goes to login if because is not logged in and `Auth.resolveUser();` will resolve to None. Can you post  Auth.resolveUser function.

Comment: Hi Levi, I updated the code. screen goes blank when i remove the resolve. resolveUser lies in the Auth factory. Even before the changes, my logging out does not work well, user profile destroys but no change in screen to Auth screen (i.e still stays at the posts page)

Comment: If you put a resolve in a state, you app does not gonna show that state if that resolved item returns none. So, you are forcing the user to be logged in, in oder to go to login page and that is not correct. If an user want to go to login page is because he is not logged in.

Comment: @levi how should I change it? Removing it from states and factory throws errors. `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: userProvider <- user`

Comment: you dont need to remove from factory, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove you resolver from your login state.

```
.state('login', {
  url: '/login',
  templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
  controller: 'AuthCtrl',
})
```

If a someone want to go to login, you can't force him to be logged in.